# Python SQL query execution time

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, performance

I have little experience working with Python and SQL. I've been learning by myself in order to get my master thesis done.

I just wrote a small script to benchmark around 50 identically structured databases, as follow:

```py
import thesis,pyodbc

# SQL Server settings
drvr = '{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}'
host = 'host_directory'
user = 'username'
pswd = 'password'
table = 'tBufferAux' # Found (by inspection) to be the table containing relevant data
column = 'Data'

# Establish a connection to SQL Server
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver=drvr, server=host, uid=user, pwd=pswd) # Setup connection

endRow = 'SELECT TOP 1 ' + column + ' FROM [' # Query template for ending row
with open(thesis.db_metadata_path(),'w') as file:
    for db in thesis.db_list():
        # Prepare queries
        countRows_query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [' + db + '].dbo.' + table
        firstRow_query = endRow + db + '].dbo.' + table + ' ORDER BY ' + column + ' ASC'
        lastRow_query = endRow + db + '].dbo.' + table + ' ORDER BY ' + column + ' DESC'
        # Execute queries
        N_rows = cnxn.cursor().execute(countRows_query).fetchone()[0]
        first_row = cnxn.cursor().execute(firstRow_query).fetchone()
        last_row = cnxn.cursor().execute(lastRow_query).fetchone()
        # Save output to text file
        file.write(db + ' ' + str(N_rows) + ' ' + str(first_row.Data) + ' ' + str(last_row.Data) + '\n')

# Close session
cnxn.cursor().close()
cnxn.close()
```

I was surprised to find this simple program to take almost 10 seconds to run, so I was wondering if that is just normal or do I have any part of my code that may be slowering down the execution. (I remind you that the for loop runs only 56 times)

Note that any function from `thesis` (customized) module has very little influence, since all of them are just variable assignments (except for `thesis.db_list()` which is a quick .txt file reading)

EDIT: [This](http://pastebin.com/1iLKLDzb) is the output .txt file generated by this program. The second column is the number of records of that table for each database.

Comment: As a side note, you have column name hard-coded in `first_row/last_row.Data`. Use `getattr(first_row,column)` to avoid that.

Comment: Is the column you're using in order by indexed? If not, it might take significant time to find the first and last row.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Nice catch! I didn't notice that. Thanks.

Comment: @JamesZ I'm not sure whether the column is indexed or not. I guess it isn't according to [this screenshot](http://imgur.com/2Y2Qo9Q). Anyway, given that I'm only running this program once, there will be no point in indexing the table first, right? (I mean, I guess the indexing action would take longer, or I am wrong?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html?highlight=timeit) is good to measure and compare the performance of single statements and code chunks (note that in [iPython](http://ipython.org), there's a built-in command to do that more easily).
- [Profilers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) split the measurement down to every function called (so are more useful for larger amounts of code).
- Note that a standalone program (more so, one in an interpreted language) has a startup (and shutdown) overhead.

Combined, 10 secs don't look like very much for a program that accesses a database.

As a test, I wrapped your program in a profiler like this:

```
def main():
<your program>
if __name__=='__main__':
    import cProfile
    cProfile.run('main()')
```

And ran it from `cygwin`'s `bash` like this:

```sh
T1=`date +%T,%N`; /c/Python27/python.exe ./t.py; echo $T1; date +%T,%N
```

The resulting table listed `connect` as the single time hog (my machine is a very fast i7 3.9GHz/8GB with a local MSSQL and SSD as the system disk):

```
     7200 function calls (7012 primitive calls) in 0.058 seconds

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
<...>
     1    0.003    0.003    0.058    0.058 t.py:1(main)
<...>
     1    0.043    0.043    0.043    0.043 {pyodbc.connect}
<...>
```

And the `date` commands showed the program itself ran for around 300ms, giving it 250ms for total overhead:

```
<...>:39,782700900
<...>:40,072717400
```

(By excluding `python` from the command line, I confirmed that other commands' overhead is negligible - about 7us)

Comment: So the connect call has a great impact on the final duration, right? Therefore, there is nothing specially wrong with my code, correct? Thanks

Comment: Yes, there's nothing wrong with your code. Apart from connection and startup, there may be other deterrents in your case like network or file I/O. The data I tested on is about an order of magnitude less than yours.